# Android HTTP post to PHP working for intranet but not working for Internet

Tags: java, php, android

I have to post some parameter from client side(android) to server side(php) using an HTTP POST request with parameters from android. I tried an example that is working in intranet(192.168.12.33) which is local ip of my system, But not working in internet(www.dillgates.pcriot.com) It's my website.

Here is my code. This is working if I replaced "192.168.2.3" instead of "www.dillgates.pcriot.com"

```
public String httppost(String param1, String param2, String file) throws JSONException
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();      
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", param1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", param2));
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.3/5mine/GeoTracker/"+file);//Working
        //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.dillgates.pcriot.com/5mine/GeoTracker/"+file);//Not working
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(GeoTrackerActivity.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the response, Whatever i got in Log cat.

[image: Logcat error]

Comment: the log shows the purticular url not available in server try loading the url manualy on a browser when it wrks the code will too and check for status code too 9probably due to accesibility chmod on ur server)

Comment: I tried loading the url manualy on a browser, Its working. But not in android. Here is my url: http://www.dillgates.pcriot.com/5mine/GeoTracker/login.php

Comment: have you tried the post method using a packet crafter ? if so whats the response then is the browser sending other values ? wether a cookie is required ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I give you my setting by using the httprequest.

-> Setting of Manifest

Add two line of permission before Application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

-> Update polic

```
ThreadPolicy mThreadPolicy = new ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(mThreadPolicy);
```

-> Using HttpURLConnection

```
String para = "username=123&password=321"
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(para.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter osw = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
osw.writeBytes(para);
osw.flush();

BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.mConnection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while((line = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    mStringBuilder.append(line);
}
String responseString = mStringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: I have tested with this same HttpURLConnection method, its working. Thanks a lot..:)